# Updating a label after deleting a cell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uilabel

First and foremost, I apologize if my title is kind of misleading compared to my question; I wasn't really sure how to word it out. Hopefully my pictures do more explanation than me. Im still at the beginning stages of iOS development and I seem to have run into my first problem. Basically, I'm creating an app where a person can input item's they have purchased and then later on sold and they can keep track of their profits/losses.

Basically, a user can add an item like the image below and it will then proceed to populate the tableview with the item title, how much they gained or lost through that transaction, and other pieces of information about that item

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaq8H.png)

Second, I have a feature where a user can delete an item from the cell by swiping left. My first problem is that the quantity (I.e 3) and total amount ("$169.82") labels don't update instantly after the deletion of the cell. My second problem is the total amount label itself; I'm able to update the quantity label by simply retrieving the count of the array where the Items Objects are stored in but I'm unable to do so with the total amount label

[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4pYz.png)

[Pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWtjY.png)

Here is a snippet of my code

```
import UIKit

var ClothesList = [String]()
var ClothesResults = [String]()
var ClothesTotalQty = AccessoryList.count
var ClothesBuy = [String]()
var ClothesSell = [String]()
var ClothesFeeArray = [String]()
var ClothesSize = [String]()
var ClothesTotalAmount = 0.0

class ViewClothes: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

// MARK: Outlets

@IBOutlet weak var ClothesQuantity: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ClothesAmount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ClothesNames: UITableView!

// MARK: Functions

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return ClothesList.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let list = ClothesNames.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"Clothes") as! CustomCells
    list.NameLabel?.text = ClothesList[indexPath.row]
    list.BuyPriceLabel?.text = "Buy Price: $\ 
(ClothesBuy[indexPath.row])"
    list.FeeLabel?.text = "Fee: \(ClothesFeeArray[indexPath.row])%"
    list.SizeLabel?.text = "Size: \(ClothesSize[indexPath.row])"
    list.SellLabel?.text = "Sell Price: $\ 
(ClothesSell[indexPath.row])"
    list.ModifiedProfitLabel?.text = ClothesResults[indexPath.row]


    return list
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if(editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete){
        ClothesList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

And here is my attempt at the solution:

```
       /* My Attempt at subtracting the removed cell from the total 
amount
        let placeholder = ClothesResults[indexPath.row]
        ClothesTotalAmount = ClothesTotalAmount - Double(placeholder)!
        ClothesResults.remove(at: indexPath.row) */

        ClothesTotalQty = ClothesList.count
        ClothesNames.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Rest of the code

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    ClothesNames.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

    ClothesNames.delegate = self
    ClothesNames.dataSource = self


    ClothesQuantity.text = String(ClothesTotalQty)
    let totalAmount = ClothesTotalAmount as NSNumber
    let totalString = currencyFormatter.string(from: totalAmount)
    ClothesAmount.text = totalString
```

Comment: you need to manage the source class to update labels , **Class/Dictionary/Array** which is used to populate the Amount,Quantity for the first time , update the respected **Class/Dictionary/Array** after deleting tableCell and just refresh label

Comment: Would you say that my attempted solution was on the right track or no? I have an idea of what I need to do but am just lost on how to do it because I would always get a "Nil" error with my solution.

Comment: Calculate `ClothesTotalAmount` again and update the label same as you did in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Got it; I must be missing something in my calculation then? Because I assume you would just subtract the amount from the deleted cell from the total amount right?

Comment: There is no need to delete. Just sum the values from the array again after the deleted one has been removed. This is cleaner as the total value will always reflect the current state of the array.

Comment: You are on right Track, just what you need to do is keep one source reference to update Text Values, Reference **Which you have used to load values first Time** , Now while deleting data just update that source only and After updating **Refresh Data**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kamran said . You need to recalculate after deleting cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
    UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if(editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete){
            ClothesList.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        ClothesQuantity.text = String(ClothesTotalQty)
        let totalAmount = ClothesTotalAmount as NSNumber
        let totalString = currencyFormatter.string(from: totalAmount)
        ClothesAmount.text = totalString

            ClothesTotalQty = ClothesList.count
            ClothesNames.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's still not working; I believe I know what my problem is: It's how I'm adding up my ClothesTotalAmount. I believe I know what to do to fix it but thank you for the help!

Comment: what you have added the code for the fix @Sweetcharge. You told the above  code is not working.'

Answer (score 0):

simply create a method. In which you have to  calculate the total amount and count of clothes from your manged array .  And call the function each time you modify the list.

```
if(editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete){  RECALCULATE YOUR AMOUNT AND CLOTHES COUNT HERE OR CALL A FUNCTION FOR SAME ClothesNames.reloadData() } }
```